# My graph made with Flot is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I'm trying to make a very simple graph with Flot in jQuery, but somehow the graph just doesn't show up.

This is my HTML for the page:

```
<!doctype html>     
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name=“description” content="This page shows plots relevant to our website">
<meta name=“keywords” content="plot, data">
<title>Boemlauwe Website</title>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="js/plot.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/plot.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>



<main>
<section>
<h1>Welcome to our plot page!</h1>
<p>On this page you will find multiple graphs and charts relevant to our lives and this website!</p>
<div id="placeholder">
</div>
</section>
</main> 
</body>

</html>
```

This is in the plot.js file for the page:

```
var data = [[10, 52], [11, 54.4], [12, 53.3], [13, 60.7], [14, 65], [15, 67.2], [16, 70.3], [17, 68.9], [18, 71.1]];


$(document).ready(function () {
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [data]);
});
```

And finally this is in the plot.css file of the page:

```
#placeholder{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

I think i did everything according to the tutorial but the graph isn't showing up on the web page. Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works okay. May be one or more of your resources are not being loaded. Use Web Inspector which can point out such things easily.

```
<!doctype html>     
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=“description” content="This page shows plots relevant to our website">
    <meta name=“keywords” content="plot, data">
    <title>Boemlauwe Website</title>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->    
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>   
    <script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>   
    <script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>   

    <style>
    #placeholder{
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
    }    
    </style>

    </head>  
    <body>    
        <main>
        <section>
        <h1>Welcome to our plot page!</h1>
        <p>On this page you will find multiple graphs and charts relevant to our lives and this website!</p>
        <div id="placeholder">
        </div>
        </section>
        </main> 


    <script type="text/javascript">

        var data = [[10, 52], [11, 54.4], [12, 53.3], [13, 60.7], [14, 65], [15, 67.2], [16, 70.3], [17, 68.9], [18, 71.1]];


        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), [data]);
        });



    </script>  

    </body>
    </html>
```